# WPF DataGrid Row Selection in TabControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a tab control in my WPF application, it has 4 tabs, each tab have different datagrid, 
I am populating the datagrid on Tab SelectionChanged.The grids are populating properly. I am having a problem is that when I click on datagrid of any tab, an extra row with default values is added .
I debugged it and found that Selectionchanged method is hitting twice when I am clicking on the datagrid
This is my TabControl with selectionchanged

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl"  Grid.Row="1" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTab}" Style="{StaticResource Light-TabControlStyle}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="LoadTabGrid" cal:View.Model="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMResource}}">
                            </cal:ActionMessage>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>                 
                    <TabItem Header="Users">
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="140"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>             
                            <DataGrid x:Name="dgotherUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDS}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                      Grid.Column="1" >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" Header="Sets" Width="*" CanUserSort="False"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Sits" Width="*" CanUserSort="False"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Gender}" Header="Sales" Width="*" CanUserSort="False"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salary}" Header="ALP" Width="*" CanUserSort="False"/>                                    
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>                            
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
```

in my ViewModel

```
 public void LoadTabGrid()
            {
                //Updating MyDS

                }
```

This is MyDS

```
ObservableCollection<UsersInfo> _usersInfo;
public ObservableCollection<UsersInfo> MyDS
{
    get { return _usersInfo; }
    set { _usersInfo= value; NotifyOfPropertyChange("MyDS"); }
}
```

I tried this in my datagrid

```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="DGSelection" cal:View.Model="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMResource}}">

                                        </cal:ActionMessage>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

With the above method, DGSelection is hitting once,and LoadTabGrid is hitting too, I need to stop hitting LoadTabGrid when I click on datagrid or atleast hit this method only once when I click on datagrid,
Its working fine when I am clicking on tab.
What should I do for this?

Comment: *I am having a problem is that when I click on datagrid of any tab, it makes all columns of last row of the grid to 0*... please explain your problem better (in your question, not here).

Comment: Thanks for telling, I have updated it

Comment: CanUserAddRows="false"

Comment: @eranotzap I have tried this too,but no luck

Comment: I see your using caliburn. 
what Dependency injection container are you using ?
Please post MyDS property .

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi come here please : 

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi is UsersInfo registered to the container ?

Comment: yes it is registered

Comment: I don't have much time , could you please come in to the chat ? 
I'm not gonna continue an on off long conversation .

Comment: Sure, I just came their

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a known issue when using Caliburn.

Caliburn resolves properties for Binding purposes and uses Property Injection to satisfy them if they do not have a value and the type is registered to the container it uses.

The EXTRA item in your ItemsSource is a value populated some how using Dependency Injection . 
Possibly from a property bound to SelectedItem (I could not get the all scope of things from the question).

Work around  :

1) Clear you ObservableCollection before populating it .
2) Make it an ObservableCollection